# DbSet not recognising its Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a problem with my DbSet in my  DbContext class.  It gives me the following error when I build my solution:

> The type or namespace name 'Student' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is my DbContext class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstMigration.Models
{
    public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext()
            : base("StudentDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StudentDbContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CodeFirst.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date),
        DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public Department Department { get; set; } // Navigation Property
    }
}
```

Department class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CodeFirst.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        public List<Student> Students { get; set; } // Navigation property
    }
}
```

Both the Student and Department class and the StudentDbContext are in the same folder.  I tried including using ProjectName.Models.Student and ProjectName.Models.Department but in vain.  Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Context lives in another namespace :

```
namespace CodeFirstMigration.Models
```

Have you tried adding a using CodeFirst.Models statement to your context like this?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CodeFirst.Models;

namespace CodeFirstMigration.Models
{
    public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext()
            : base("StudentDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StudentDbContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}
```